# Which one is proper, “room 501” or “Room 501”?

Tags: capitalization

Should the word *room* be capitalized when followed by a number, such as room 501 or Room 501?

Comment: There is a TV show (in UK) called Room 101 but if that's my room in a hotel it would be room 101. The first is a [proper noun (or name)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/proper_noun).

Comment: Weather, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Hello, Weather, just now I found a rule mentioned in an essay concerning capitalization from Editorial Style Guide as follows: "Room
The word room when used to designate a particular room should be capitalized. When a room number is combined with a letter (whether placed before or after the number), a hyphen should not be used to separate the letter from the room number.

Example: Your class is located in Room A133."

Comment: A style guide is a matter of opinion.

Comment: It's on the website of Lewis University https://www.lewisu.edu/welcome/offices/marketing/editorial_capit.htm#:~:text=The%20word%20room%20when%20used%20to%20designate%20a,Example%3A%20Your%20class%20is%20located%20in%20Room%20A133.

Comment: So either way is proper?

Comment: That's a "house" style guide from their Office of Marketing and Communications which begins "In general, avoid unnecessary capitalization".

Comment: I agree that if a lecture room's name is **Room A133** then that is what should be used. But in general, the noun is not a proper name, for example house 42 in a street, or locker 100 at a station.

Comment: I see. So a hotel room may not be capitalized as room 301, is that right?

Comment: As I said, it is also a matter of editorial style. Lewis Uni obviously thinks otherwise. You *may* capitalise it if you think there is a good reason to.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Now it's much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider "Room 501" it to be the name of the room then capitalise it.  If you consider the word "room" to be a common noun, and 501 to be its name then you wouldn't capitalise it.  So you can express a subtle difference in meaning by the use of capital letters.

If 501 means that it is the five hundredth and first room in some sequence then "room" is probably a common noun.  But it if means the first room on floor five, then the name of the room is probably "Room 501" and you should use capitals.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I mean any one hotel room with a number, like Room 501 on the fifth floor, Room 623 on the sixth floor.

Comment: I'd go with the capital letter.